# Check valve with precise cracking pressure

Tags: pressure, valves, pressure-vessel

I have two containers of air, one at 100 kPa and rising, the other at 30 kPa and decreasing. I need a valve that lets air through when the pressure difference is >70 kPa. Where would I find a valve like that? If nowhere, do you have any pointers on how to make one?

Answer (score 3):

Check Valves are available with adjustable cracking pressures, using a preload spring to control the poppet force, for example: http://www.my-ssp-usa.com/products/valves/check-valves/adjustable-cpa

It's important to note, however, that there is a degree of histeresis with these valves, and once open, they will not close if the pressure difference drops a bit - it will have to drop lower than your application may allow. A Back Pressure Regulator may be more suitable.

[image: Adjustable Check Valve:]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Although the industrial ones are insanely expensive. I found these: 
http://www.solenoid-valve.world/other-products/FRL/r200?gclid=Cj0KCQjw6rXeBRD3ARIsAD9ni9DhqMAjh1xweQvb0me3lnKGTXJ_DJ7aWoTIXLhwQIPuKMJeO9J5vVcaAr30EALw_wcB

https://www.bes.co.uk/adjustable-pressure-reducing-valve-15-22mm-22301?ref=gs&photo=true&gclid=Cj0KCQjw6rXeBRD3ARIsAD9ni9A-_rtGEflQ9EboiFz-XdoxnDNLJ-C45lCb_Ue1Tr0uJQ-Vg6SUM7MaAnZbEALw_wcB
Is any of these two what I'm looking for?

Comment: No - a pressure regulator sets a downstream pressure when given a high upstream pressure, but a back pressure regulator sets an upstream pressure when given a low downstream pressure.

Comment: But isn't a pressure regulator essentially a check valve? If it relieves pressure on the other side after reaching a critical value, that would work for me (I now realize I misspoke, I don't care about the lower pressure, I just need the pressurized chamber to stay close to 100 kPa). Although it would still depend on the pressure on the other side?

Comment: A pressure regulator doesn't care what the upstream pressure is. If the downstream is lower than the setpoint, it will open to let more gas in. If it's higher, it will close. This doesn't sound like what you want?

Comment: Oh so these regulators only depend on the lower pressure? Yeah, that's not helpful.

Comment: Exactly. A back pressure regulator is (probably) what you need - although I don't know exactly what your application is...

Comment: I also thought I'll get a pressure sensor in the high pressure chamber, ass a valve and open it periodically to let air out. It will all be controlled by an arduino so might still work. Thanks for your help!